# replace copied value to Table with a new calculated value and button

Tags: excel, vba, excel-tables, listobject

I have a table which I insert rows to with this code:

```
Sub Invoice_InsertProduct()

If Sheet1.Range("Z6").Value = "" Then

MsgBox "Selecciona producto"
    Sheet1.Range("Z6").Select
    Else
      Dim ttCotizacion As ListObject
      Set ttCotizacion = Sheet1.ListObjects("tCotizacion")
      Dim FilaTabla As ListRow
      If ttCotizacion.ListRows.Count = 1 And Sheet1.Range("Z29").Value = "" Then
      Set FilaTabla = ttCotizacion.ListRows(1)
      FilaTabla.Range.Cells(1).Value = Sheet1.Range("X6").Value
      FilaTabla.Range.Cells(2).Value = Sheet1.Range("Y6").Value
      FilaTabla.Range.Cells(3).Value = Sheet1.Range("Z6").Value
      FilaTabla.Range.Cells(5).Value = Sheet1.Range("AF6").Value
      FilaTabla.Range.Cells(6).Value = Sheet1.Range("AG6").Value
      Else
      Set FilaTabla = ttCotizacion.ListRows.Add
      FilaTabla.Range.Cells(1).Value = Sheet1.Range("X6").Value
      FilaTabla.Range.Cells(2).Value = Sheet1.Range("Y6").Value
      FilaTabla.Range.Cells(3).Value = Sheet1.Range("Z6").Value
      FilaTabla.Range.Cells(5).Value = Sheet1.Range("AF6").Value
      FilaTabla.Range.Cells(6).Value = Sheet1.Range("AG6").Value
        End If
    Sheet1.Range("X6").Value = ""
    Sheet1.Range("Z6").Value = ""
    Sheet1.Range("B4").Select
End If
End Sub
```

Now what I want to do is after all rows are added to Table("tCotizacion"), user can use a button with a new Sub Prorate_UnitPrice() that will prorate proportionally a number named "nCostLogTot" (Y9) through all values that were copied to:
FilaTabla.Range.Cells(6).Value = Sheet1.Range("AG6").Value 'Unit Price

The formula which gives the expected value would be:

'New Unit Price
=IF(ISNUMBER("nCostLogT"),((tCotizacion[ProductAmount]/nTotalBalance)*nCostLogT)/tCotizacion[ProductQuantity],0) + FilaTabla.Range.Cells(6).Value = Sheet1.Range("AG6").Value

But necessary to go through all rows in Table (tCotizacion) to last row and replace previous value.
Example would be:

nCostLogT= $600

ProductQuantity / Unit Price/ Product Amount

1. ```
   100       /   $20     /     $ 2000
   ```
2. ```
   200      /   $30     /      $ 6000
               nTotal Balance= $8000
   ```

Prorate Delivery Cost:

1. ((($2000/$8000)*600)/100)+20= $21.5 New Unit Price
2. ((($6000/$8000)*600)/200)+30= $32.25 New Unit Price

Expected table

ProductQuantity / Unit Price/ Product Amount

1. 100        /   $21.5   /     $ 2150
2. 200       /   $32.25  /      $ 6450
   nTotal Balance= $8600

The table has 7 columns… header name are:

```
Column 1 = ProductQuantity
Column 2 = Unit
Column 3 = Product
Column 4 = SKU
Column 5 = DeliveryDay
Column 6 = UnitPrice
Column 7 = ProductAmount
```

Hope my explanation is clear enough for all.

TIA!!

Comment: How many cols in `tCotizacion` ? Please show all fields (header cells' contents).

Comment: Please DO NOT edit the tag information back into the title. It's useless noise and clutter. The tag system here works extremely well, and does not need help. For more information, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/172661.

Comment: @taller it has 7 columns… header name are: 1= ProductQuantity, 2=Unit, 3=Product, 4=SKU, 5=DeliveryDay, 6=UnitPrice, 7=ProductAmount

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- ***Opetion 1***: add a temp col to calculate the new price

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [ListObject.ListColumns property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.listobject.listcolumns?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm734086)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

> [ListColumn.DataBodyRange property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.listcolumn.databodyrange?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm738082)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub UpdateTable1()
    Dim oTab As ListObject, lastCol As ListColumn
    Dim oSht As Worksheet
    Const PRICE_COL = "[UnitPrice]"
    Const TAB_NAME = "tCotizacion"
'    Const TAB_NAME = "Table1" ' for testing
    Set oSht = ActiveSheet
    If IsNumeric(Range("nCostLogT").Value) Then
        Set oTab = oSht.ListObjects(TAB_NAME)
        With oTab
            With .HeaderRowRange
                .Cells(.Cells.Count).Offset(, 1).Value = "TempCol"
            End With
            Set lastCol = .ListColumns(.ListColumns.Count)
            lastCol.DataBodyRange.FormulaR1C1 = "=(([@ProductAmount]/SUM([ProductAmount])*nCostLogT/[@ProductQuantity])+[@UnitPrice])"
            oSht.Range(.Name & PRICE_COL).Value = lastCol.DataBodyRange.Value
            lastCol.Range.Clear
            .Resize .Range.Resize(, .ListColumns.Count - 1)
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

---

- ***Opetion 2***: load table into an array and calculate the new price

```
Sub UpdateTable2()
    Dim oTab As ListObject, lastCol As ListColumn
    Dim oSht As Worksheet, arrData, i As Long
    Dim TotalAmt As Double, CostLog As Double
    Dim iQty As Long, iPrice As Long, iAmt As Long
    Const QTY_COL = "ProductQuantity"
    Const PRICE_COL = "UnitPrice"
    Const AMT_COL = "ProductAmount"
    Const TAB_NAME = "tCotizacion"
    ' Const TAB_NAME = "Table1" ' for testing
    Set oSht = ActiveSheet
    If IsNumeric(Range("nCostLogT").Value) Then
        CostLog = Range("nCostLogT").Value
        Set oTab = oSht.ListObjects(TAB_NAME)
        With oTab
            iQty = .ListColumns(QTY_COL).Index
            iPrice = .ListColumns(PRICE_COL).Index
            iAmt = .ListColumns(AMT_COL).Index
            TotalAmt = Application.Sum(.ListColumns(iAmt).DataBodyRange)
            arrData = .DataBodyRange.Value
            For i = 1 To UBound(arrData)
                arrData(i, iPrice) = ((arrData(i, iAmt) / TotalAmt) * CostLog / arrData(i, iQty)) + arrData(i, iPrice)
            Next
            .DataBodyRange.Value = arrData
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks soooo muuuuch!! option 1 works perfectly!! UR AMAZING!